# Jquery sliding menu

Tags: jquery, if-statement, menu, slider

Im trying to create a downward sliding menu, with a little button.
It has to be with only 1 button and I cant work out the if - height slang.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function () {
  if ($("#menu").is("height:30px")) {
    $("#menu").animate({"height":"500px"}, 500);
  } else {
    $("#menu").animate({"height":"30px"}, 500);
  }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
 <button id="button" value="littlebutton"></button>
<div id="menu">this is the menu</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am/have been googling, and im in a little bit of a hurry.

Greetings, chris.

***EDIT:***

Now the first part has been done and I thought the rest wouldn't be hard to do myself.
I need text in it ofcourse but the text does not scroll, it just hides.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#button").click(function () {
  if ($("#menu").css("height")=="30px") {
    $("#menu").animate({"height":"275px"}, 500);
    $("#text").scrollDown(500);
  } else {  
    $("#text").scrollUp(500);
    $("#menu").animate({"height":"30px"}, 500);

  }
});
});
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#CCCCCC">

    <div id="menu">this is the menu <button id="button" value="littlebutton"></button><div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sed magna quis arcu lacinia euismod ac blandit nunc. Proin sit amet risus turpis, quis tempor magna. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum ac risus leo, quis eleifend tellus. Sed eu vestibulum justo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra.</div></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I also need the text to "slide/scroll" when the bottom hits it.
How to do this?

***EDIT2***

Nevermind, used scroll instead of slide...
Typo, the hell of the programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .css() I think  if ($("#menu").css("height")=="30px") etc give it a shot and let me know the result

Answer (score 0):

You have to use .css to check the height value.

Try this code:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
  if ($("#menu").css("height")=="30px") {
    $("#menu").animate({"height":"500px"}, 500);
  } else {
    $("#menu").animate({"height":"30px"}, 500);
  }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9WMmg/)**